# How to use variables in Pattern.compile on java in selenium RC

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to compare the date in the field corresponds to the current day.
In selenium ide is solved very simply:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeExpression</td>
    <td>javascript{var date = new Date();date.getDate()+' '+date.getMonth();}</td>
    <td>t_date</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeExpression</td>
    <td>javascript{var date = new Date();(date.getDate() -1)+' 'date.getMonth();}</td>
    <td>y_date</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>assertText</td>
    <td>//div[@id='a-articles-container']/a[3]/span[2]/span[2]/span[2]</td>
    <td>regexp:(${t_date}*)|(${y_date}*)</td>
</tr>
```

But when I export the html code in java, I get an illegal repetition: `Pattern.compile("(${t_date}*)|(${y_date}*)")`

My java code looks like this:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

String t_date = c.get(c.DAY_OF_MONTH) + " " + c.get(c.MONTH);
String y_date = (c.get(c.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1) + " " + c.get(c.MONTH);

assertTrue(Pattern.compile("(${t_date}*)|(${y_date}*)").matcher(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='a-articles-container']/a[5]/span[2]/span[2]/span[2]")).getText()).find());
```

I can compare the text with variable y_date

```
assertTrue(Pattern.compile(y_date).matcher(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='a-articles-container']/a[5]/span[2]/span[2]/span[2]")).getText()).find());
```

or t_date

```
 assertTrue(Pattern.compile(t_date).matcher(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='a-articles-container']/a[5]/span[2]/span[2]/span[2]")).getText()).find());
```

But not with both at once!

How can I use "or" operator in a pattern to compare the explanatory variables is whether the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not support [String Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) like Ruby, PHP etc. so you cannot write "${variable}" and expect it to work. What is happening in your case is the ${t_date} is remaining in that form and Pattern.compile is trying to interpret it as a regular expression, and { and } are reserved characters.

However [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) with using placeholders like %s works as a good substitute.

What I believe you want is the following.

```
assertTrue(Pattern.compile(String.format("(%s*)|(%s*)", t_date, y_date))
        .matcher(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='a-articles-container']/a[5]/span[2]/span[2]/span[2]")).getText()).find());
```